# How to make a container take up the height of the parent widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a card layout which looks like the following:

[image: Layout]

The code for it it as follows:

```
Card(
        color: tap ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 3.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              **Container(
                height: !widget.menuItem.image.endsWith('/')? 70.0 : 0.0,
                width: !widget.menuItem.image.endsWith('/')? 70.0 : 0.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0), topRight: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(widget.menuItem.image),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover
                  ),
                ),**
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 8.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          howManyThere() > 0 ? "${howManyThere()} x " : '',
                          style: addBTNHighlight,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            widget.menuItem.item_name,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: tap ? TitleWhite18Bold : Title18bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.menuItem.description,
                        //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: tap ? SubTitleWhite13 : SubTitle13,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "£" + num.parse(widget.menuItem.price).toStringAsFixed(2),
                        style: tap ? priceHighlightSelected : priceHighlight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 6.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                      child: Text("ADD", style: tap ? priceHighlightWhite : addBTNHighlight)),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

As you can see that I am almost there with my desired layout but with one small issue which can be seen in first and last item. Because of the given width and height of the image container, it leaves a gap on top and bottom.

What I would like to happen is that the width to stay the same but the height to be flexible and adjust with the height of the card itself. Is it possible?

When I remove the height attribute of the container with the image, I get a blank space of the image

UPDATE: I tried LayoutBuilder as well but without any Luck, it throws 'Incorrect use of ParentWidget' Exception. The code I used is as follows:

```
Row(
            children: [
              widget.menuItem.image.endsWith('/')
                  ? Container()
                  : **LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints){
                  return Container(
                    width: 70.0,
                    height: constraints.minHeight,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(widget.menuItem.image),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }**
              ),
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. You could try removing `height:70` and wrapping your `Row` inside an `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

Comment: use BoxFit.fitHeight or fill

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: !widget.menuItem.image.endsWith('/')? 70.0 : 0.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0), topRight: Radius.circular(5.0)),
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(widget.menuItem.image),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: I get all sorts of rendering errors doing this way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your description text which overflow your desired max height. You can try to constraint your `Container` with a `height: 70.0` or you can add to your `Text` widget the property `maxLines: 1`.

Comment: Thanks but it is not a problem, it’s a feature. The description should not be trimmed to one line.

Comment: so you want to resize the photo to the max height ?

Comment: Yes that’s the desire

Comment: than if you let the `height` of the image `Container` may help you. Othewise try to give `double.infinity` value

Comment: Ok.. well try to use `LayoutBuilder`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html and use the `maxHeight` property

Comment: Tried Layout builder but got an error. Updated code above

Comment: Try wrap all `Row` in `LayoutBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutBuilder` only give you **constraints** that parent pass to child, which is something like `100 < width < 200, 300 < height < infinity`. At this point the height of all texts on the right are not determined yet, so it is impossible to determined the height of image base on that.

One way to do this is to assign `key` to each list item, get item heights after everything is layout, the rebuild with those fixed height. This will become a two pass process and is less efficient.

The official solution to this is `IntrinsicHeight`, which conceptually do the same thing, but in a more optimized way.

Here is a minimum example:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            // This is where magic happened
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage('https://cataas.com/cat'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      // just put some random text with dynamic height
                      'Text\n' * (Random().nextInt(4) + 4),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Damandroid "Sorry this didn't work" is not going to help you.

Comment: Sorry but I have given up on it after so many days and changing strategy seemed a better option for now. I have changed the layout now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove height constraints, then
Try replacing `fit: BoxFit.cover` with `BoxFit.fitHeight` or `BoxFit.fill`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill the image with card height you can give container required height and wrap the `Image` widget in `AspectRatio` widget with `ratio` 1. This will always helps image widget to fill parent card height. Have a look in below code.

##### Parent Widget

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
  height: 100,
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
          child: _pictureWidget(widget.menuItem.image),
        ),
       /// Replace `Container` with the needed widget
       Expanded(child: Container()),
     ],
   ),
 )
```

##### _pictureWidget

```
Widget _picture(String url) {
    return _pictureWidget(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0), topRight: Radius.circular(5.0)),
      child: Image.network(
        url != null ? url : "",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
            ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
          if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                  ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                      loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                  : null,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```